# Getting 'null' by using the getAttribute() Method

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the value of the attribute "data-original" but I'm getting null

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-container">
            <img src="preview/beach-preview.jpg" 
            alt="Beach image"
            data-original="full/beach-full.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="preview/bridge-preview.jpg" 
            alt="Bridge image"
            data-original="full/bridge-full.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code of js where I loop through all the images containing data-original attribute and add a event listener of event click to get the value of attribute

**JS**

```
const imgContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');

imgContainer.forEach( (x) => {
    x.addEventListener('click', () => {
     
        const imageSource = x.getAttribute('data-original');
        console.log(imageSource);

       
    });
});
```

Comment: when is this code called?

Comment: Your `img-container` would need to have a `data-original` attribute, for this to work. The example you are giving us does not

Comment: I edited the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function looks correct:

```js
const imgContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');

imgContainer.forEach( (x) => {
    x.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const imageSource = x.getAttribute('data-original');
        console.log(imageSource)     
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: lightgray; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container" data-original="source1"></div>
<div class="img-container" data-original="source2"></div>
<div class="img-container" data-original="source3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not define your custom `attribute` `data-original`.

Change :

```
<div class="img-container" >
```

To :

```
 <div class="img-container" data-original="data">
```